# How can I query for "AssignedTo = [ME]" using REST?

Tags: rest

It is quite common to use "Assigned To = [Me]" in SharePoint views to list the tasks / items which are assigned to the current user. This of course includes both the items which are *directly* assigned to the current user, as well as those items which are *indirectly* assigned to the current user (i.e. as a member of a Group).

I can happily do this in Server Side API code using the following CAML Query:

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef ID="Assigned To" />
            <Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value>
        </Eq>
        <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
        </Membership>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

Does anyone know how I can do this using the REST API?

Comment: I never have done this but did you try to use the odata $filter field?
You should write something like $filter=UserId eq yourUserID

Comment: That doesn't take care of the <Membership> element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very interesting question and good answers. I have tested it on a usual Tasks list and got it working after trial and error. The link provided above, [Using CAML in REST requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_ListGetItems), is good, although it contains syntax errors and unintroduced variables that makes it harder to try out the examples. Robert Kaucher has a working solution, even though it contained a little misspelling, that's why it caused a 500 error for me. I'd rather recommend to not to put the whole CAML query into a URL query string, it can stop working in an older IE browser due the url length restrictions. It is better to put the CAML query into a request body.

In my out-of-the-box Tasks list, the following CAML Query works:

```
<View>
   <Query>
      <Where>
          <Or>
              <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
                  <Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value>
              </Eq>
              <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
                  <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
              </Membership>
          </Or>
      </Where>
   </Query>
</View>
```

Pay attention to **<FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />**, not *<FieldRef ID="Assigned To" />*.

Here is the working jQuery.ajax-code:

```
var viewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq><Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' /> </Membership></Or></Where></Query></View>";
$.ajax({
  url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/getitems",
  method: "POST",
  data: "{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, \"ViewXml\": \"" 
      + viewXml + "\" }}",
  headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  }
});
```

If you prefer to use SP.RequestExecutor and be independent of jQuery, just replace `data` with `body` in the request options. Make sure you have the SP.RequestExecutor.js loaded into your page first:

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/getitems",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, \"ViewXml\": \"" + viewXml + "\" }}",
  headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  }
});
```

SP.RequestExecutor will make it easier to rewrite the code to an app and use it in a cross-domain scenario.

To try this request I have used [PostMan](http://tech.bool.se/basic-rest-request-sharepoint-using-postman/). 
[image]

And Developer Tools in my browser, to see results without writing ajax callbacks.
[image]

Comment: BTW, I copied the question's CAML directly and assumed it was correct based on the what the OP said.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following. Notice that you need to use `POST` as you are sending data. You also need the `<View>`and `<Query>`tags.

```
<View>
   <Query>
      <Where>
          <Or>
              <Eq>
                  <FieldRef ID="Assigned To" />
                  <Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value>
              </Eq>
              <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
                  <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
              </Membership>
          </Or>
      </Where>
   </Query>
</View>
```

Here I am sending a POST to 'Test List' with the view XML from above.

```
var viewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef ID='Assigned To' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq><Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' /> </Membership></Or></Where></Query></View>";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }, 
    url: 'https://mysharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle(\'Test List\')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"' + viewXml + '"}', 
    success: function(data){console.log(data); },
    failure: function(data){console.log(data); } 
});
```

Comment: did you actually try this code?
I've had to add the content-length and change "failure" to "error"

Comment: also getting "Bad Request" (invalid JSON object)

Comment: Need to see your code. Can you add it as an edit?

Comment: Oh wait! I think I see the issue.

Comment: The quotes in my CAML wouldn't have worked in the JSON request. Try it with what I edited.

Comment: Beauty .. it worked .. but thanks also to Paul Shaeflin (he got in with the idea first .. but you get the answer for providing _working_ source code!) :)

Comment: Well, architects usually just wave our hands and provide generalities. We leave the actual work to others. :)

Answer (score 4):

The GetItems method in the REST api accepts a CAML query. Have you tried that?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_ListGetItems

Comment: Aha .. might be what I needed, I'll give it a go

Comment: This isn't an app and I'm not using the "Executor" .. do you have an example using $.ajax ?

Comment: everytime I try to add the "Membership" element it just stops working

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you need.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Accounting/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle(\'Tasks\')/Items?$filter=AssignedTo eq ' + _spPageContextInfo.userId,
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this account for instances where AssignedTo is a group the user is in?

Comment: No it doesn't (Tested it)