# Do REST only uses search index to retrieve information / do the data have to be indexed - SharePoint

Tags: 2013, search, rest

I know that I can use search REST api to fetch data from SharePoint. But is there a way to get a list without having to index the list?

I'm having a problem that search (Continues crawl) is to slow to index the list. I'm trying to find out how I can get a list from a user personal sites using REST instead of a Content Search Web part.

Let me refrase this question:
If I add a item to a list, and the search have not yet crawled it. Could I with REST get information from the list?

The list is another site collection :)

Comment: But do this uses the search index or does it fetch information from the list? Will I get the information if it's not in the index?

Comment: Does it have restriction on site collections? Can I ask for a list in another site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use REST to query a list regardless of Search and its crawl status.

You can use REST to list items from any list on any site in any site collection.

To view a list: `<site>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('My List')` or `<site>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')`

To view list items: `<site>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('My List')/items`

Closest things you can get to a restriction are that the user must have permissions to the list, and if in an app, the app must have the appropriate permissions as well.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx) is a link to get started with REST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST to query a list using the GetItems method and passing in a CAML query. Unfortunately, this will be subject to any list throttling limits. I recommend you search on values that are indexed columns in the list. The following thread explains a lot how to do this.
[How can I query for "AssignedTo = [ME]" using REST?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94030/how-can-i-query-for-assignedto-me-using-rest)